# C++ текст в окне не обновляется

Tags: c++

Добрый день. У меня есть окно со списком и текстовое поле. Хочу что бы при клике на элемент списка, в текстовом поле появлялся аналогичный элементу списка текст. 
Все вроде бы отрабатывает, но текст в текстовом поле сразу не меняется. Сколько ни кликай по элементам в текстовом поле старая надпись. Однако, как только окно становиться неактивным, текстовое поле обновляется и все становиться ок. Пробовал добавлять UpdateWindow(hStatic) и иже с ними, но они отрабатывают так же после того, как окно станет не активным.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <string>       
#include <sstream> 
#include <iostream>

#define ID_LIST 3000

    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    static HWND hStatic,hListBox;
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    int ultem;
    char Buf[80];
    char szTitle[]="текст";

    switch(Message) {
        case WM_CREATE:{
            hListBox=CreateWindow("listbox",NULL,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|LBS_WANTKEYBOARDINPUT|WS_VSCROLL,30,30,100,30,hwnd,(HMENU)ID_LIST,hInstance,NULL);
            SendMessage(hListBox, WM_SETREDRAW, FALSE, 0L);

            SendMessage(hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0,(LPARAM)(LPSTR)"Первый");
            SendMessage(hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0,(LPARAM)(LPSTR)"Второй");
            SendMessage(hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0,(LPARAM)(LPSTR)"Третий");

            SendMessage(hListBox, WM_SETREDRAW, TRUE, 0L);

            InvalidateRect(hListBox, NULL, TRUE);
            hStatic=CreateWindow("static","текст",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,100,200,100,100,hwnd,(HMENU)0,hInstance,NULL);
            break;
        }
        case WM_COMMAND:{
            wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
            wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
                ultem=(int)SendMessage(hListBox,LB_GETCURSEL,0,0L);
                if(ultem!=LB_ERR)
                    {
                    SendMessage(hListBox,LB_GETTEXT,ultem,(LPARAM)Buf);             
                    SendMessage(hStatic, WM_SETREDRAW, FALSE, 0L);
                    SendMessage(hStatic, WM_SETTEXT, 0,(LPARAM)Buf);
                    SendMessage(hStatic, WM_SETREDRAW, TRUE, 0L);
                    InvalidateRect(hStatic, NULL, TRUE);
                    }                   
            InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }           
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
    }       
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc; 
    HWND hwnd; 
    MSG msg; 

    memset(&wc,0,sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc; 
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); 
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,"WindowClass","Caption",WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, /* x */
        CW_USEDEFAULT, /* y */
        640, /* width */
        480, /* height */
        NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: А какой смысл вы вкладываете в использование локальной переменной `hInstance`, которая нигде осмысленно не инициализируется?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду в WndProc? А как она должна быть инициирована?

Comment: Выкиньте ее вообще. При создании child окон не надо указывать `hInstance`. Передавайте просто `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Банальное добавление отладочной печати в ваш обработчик `WM_COMMAND` показало бы, что он *не вызывается вообще* при смене выбора в списке.

Ваш список создан без стиля `LBS_NOTIFY`. Поэтому никаких `WM_COMMAND` при смене выбора он главному окну не шлет. Поэтому ваш обработчик смены текста даже и не вызывается.

Добавьте `LBS_NOTIFY` при создании списка.

---

Эти манипуляции с `WM_SETREDRAW` для статического контрола нинафиг не нужны. И инвалидировать после смены текста достаточно только сам контрол. Все окно инвалидировать не надо.

Comment: СПАСИБО! Помогло)